# List Object in Amazon S3 through Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a list of objects in an  Amazon S3 bucket using the S3FileSystem.

```
val exists = s3FS.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("s3n://bucketname/Daily/DailyCash.TXT"))
println(exists)
val sels=s3FS.listFiles(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("s3n://bucketname//Daily"),true)
println(sels)
```

Getting the below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File s3n://bucketname/ does not exist.
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem.listStatus(S3FileSystem.java:194)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1482)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1522)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.<init>(FileSystem.java:1798)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1797)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1780)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$5.<init>(FileSystem.java:1842)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listFiles(FileSystem.java:1839)
```

Comment: What sdk are you using? `s3FS ` it's not the usual `AmazonS3Client` client. When do you get the error? executing the exists method or the listFiles? Did you check that you have set permissions properly?

Comment: Trying to use `S3Filesystem` or `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem`. I do have the permissions as I am able to read content of file to RDD using `sc.textfike("")`. 
Only facing issue while trying to get a list of objects in a bucket or it folder. 
Please let me know if there is any other way to get the list of objects from S3 using `AmazonS3Client`

Comment: Note that the permissions to listObjects and to getObject are different and need to allow both: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this with AWS SDK instead of mix and match with Hadoop classes **and only for listing objects**, NOT recommending to load huge datasets.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.{AmazonS3Client, AmazonS3URI}

val location = "s3://bucketname/Daily/DailyCash.TXT"

val awsCredentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()
val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials)
val s3Uri = new AmazonS3URI(location)

val objects: ObjectListing = s3Client.listObjects(s3Uri.getBucket)
```